# WebStorm & Ionic 2: ram and performance issue

Tags: typescript, angular, ide, webstorm, ionic2

I'm working on an hybrid application using Ionic 2 and webstorm. I usually work on Windows 7, Windows 10 and sometimes with ubuntu 16.04 (but only windows matters here). I code with WebStorm 2016.1.3 on a 64bits machine.

All my non-ionic projects work very well but when I play with Ionic,
webstorm has problems with RAM. Some very basic actions take several seconds to finish (moving the cursor, save, edit...). I often have a popup popup which tells me to add memory space for WS. But even if I give webstorm more ram, nothing changes. I've switched from 512Mo to
1024Mb, then to 2048Mo and I'm going to give 4096Mo. It's insane.

I've tried to use ionic only directly on my smartphone via `ionic run`
(instead of `ionic serve`) in case ionic runs a kind of VM or
whatever, but that doesn't work.

I can't try with another IDE right now but with enhanced notepads, I don't have any issue (Sublime Text, Notepad++...).

I work on different machines and the same issue comes accross all these machines.

(I'm well stuffed, have a lot of ram, ssd etc. So it can't be a hardware issue).

DDo you have any idea ? Did you face a similar issue ?

Comment: please try excluding the build target directory (www/build folder and other dynamically generated folders) from project (Mark directory as/Excluded) - does it make things any better?

Comment: I can also suggest disabling 'Unused JavaScript/ActionScript global symbol' inspection (Settings | Editor | Inspections, JavaScript/General)

Comment: It seems to be a lot better, thank you. I've just make a rapid test, I'll do a deep test later :)

Comment: Okay so this is definitely an answer. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and the problem was the **indexing process**.

*Solution*: **exclude the folder "www"**.
Righ click -> Mark Directory as -> Exclude.

*Explanation*: 
Every time you compile or generate binaries when the sources change, the content of the folder "www" changes and Webstorm launch its indexing process to count with those files in searches, etc. Since that code is generated based on the source code, the content is not relevant because we have it in the source files so we can ignore those files from indexing and that way, to have a better performance when ionic built the app dynamically after changes.